# Astropy: SkyCoord.from_name() - module 'urllib.request' has no attribute 'HTTPSHandler'

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, astropy

I'm new to Python and just started learning this. I'm trying to figure out how to work with the Jupyter Notebook for searching for an object name in online databases. I wrote two versions of the code (for Betelgeuse and M1), but both versions give an error: *module 'urllib.request' has no attribute 'HTTPSHandler'*

```
from astropy.coordinates import SkyCoord, EarthLocation
betelgeuse = SkyCoord.from_name(’Betelgeuse’)
print(betelgeuse)
```

and:

```
from astropy import coordinates as coord
crab = SkyCoord.from_name('M1')
print(crab)
```

According to the urllib docs, *If the Python installation has SSL support (i.e., if the ssl module can be imported), HTTPSHandler will also be added.*

I tried to `import ssl` and `import urllib.request` by including the appropriate line at the very beginning of the code variants being compiled, but without success, the error persists.

I'm working in Jupyter Notebook at https://jupyter.org/try-jupyter/lab/index.html and would like to understand the reasons for the error. If I connect the modules incorrectly, I would like to learn. If these are shortcomings of the web version - I would like to get confirmation of this.

Many thanks!

Comment: This appears to be related: https://github.com/koenvo/pyodide-http/issues/33 , and it's probably (partly) a Pyodide issue.

Comment: @9769953 of course `import ssl`. My typo

Comment: I think the linked GitHub issue indicates some shortcoming of the web/Pyodide version. It seems to suggest possible workarounds, but these may not be applicable for you, or simply won't work. Since the server is out of your control, it may simply be something that you can't fix. In that case, the only "workaround" means finding the coordinates more or less manually, and don't use AstroPy's name look-up service.

Comment: @9769953 none of the methods suggested in linked GitHub worked, the error persists